# Onelogin G Suite with login/pass

Tags: single-sign-on, google-oauth, saml, onelogin, google-workspace

I have a OneLogin account and have set up `G Suite`. Everything works but I have a couple problems:

1. After configuring `G Suite`, if a user logs into *Gmail* to write an email, the user gets redirected to the OneLogin login page. How can I disable this?
2. Since there is no password with oauth, how should I configure *Gmail* clients with `oauth/saml` enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't disable this. You can configure IP who don't apply the SSO.
2. You need to create application specific password, you can create one after you enable the second factor.